# PowerShell script - check for exit code

Tags: powershell, if-statement, iis, powershell-remoting

I have the following script:

```
foreach ($server in $ProductList.$SelectedServer) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential domain\user -ScriptBlock {
        Import-Module WebAdministration
        echo "restarting AppPool $args[0] ... on $args[1]"
        Restart-WebAppPool -Name $args[0] -ErrorAction Stop
        echo "Restarted WebApp $args[0] on $args[1]"
    }
} -ArgumentList $SelectedAppPool, $Server
```

I would like to check if the `Restart-WebAppPool` command executes successfully. If it does I echo 'it worked' else echo 'It did not work'.

The goal is to provide a simple plain english message rather than the typical unhandled exception.

Comment: The code you posted can't possibly work. `foreach` loops don't have a parameter `-ArgumentList`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers yeah had to move that up to the Invoke-Command part. Thanks for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, you're most of the way there, I don't know off the top of my head under what circumstances `Restart-WebAppPool` throws a terminating error, but in order to do anything with them you'll need try/catch blocks:

```
try {
    Restart-WebAppPool -Name $args[0] -ErrorAction stop
    Write-Host "It worked"
} catch {
    Write-Host "It did not work"
    # Error handling goes here.
}
```

The "It worked" output will only be displayed if no terminating errors are thrown by `Restart-WebAppPool`

Comment: Adding to this, @Joe, you might want to send a PSCredential object instead of just a Username as parameters for -Credential. Otherwise, Inside a for loop, you will have to enter the password as many times as it iterates.

Comment: Thanks @Windos. That did the trick. Just for clarification. Does the try / catch actually execute the code block in the try section ? Or does it simply try it /dry run ?

Comment: @joebegborg07 it actually executes it, but it'll stop as soon as it runs into a terminating error and jump straight to the catch block (hence you won't see "It worked" if there's an error.)